# Connect Jupyter Notebook (locally) to AWS s3 without SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

Is it possible to connect jupyter notebook that is running locally to one of the buckets on AWS S3 without using SageMaker and involving **no or with** access and secret keys?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it is possible. You can find a tutorial [here](https://carolynlangen.com/2017/11/22/interacting-with-aws-s3-using-python-in-a-jupyter-notebook/).
However, you'll need to create an IAM role. The process is described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/backup-to-s3-cli/).

Answer (score 3):

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id="<Type your key>",aws_secret_access_key="<type your sec key>")
bucket = "<your bucket name>"
file_name = "<your file name>"
s3_clientobj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_name)
```